# Javascript setTimeout Parameter Issue (The I'm Using an Anonymous Function Version)

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I can't believe that I'm having an issue with this. My setTimeout is:

```
setTimeout(function(){showContent(entries, 0);}, 500);
```

I also tried:

```
(function(entries, index){
    clear_show_content = setTimeout(function(){
                                               showContent(entries, index);
                                              }, 500);
                          })(entries, 0);
```

and in `showContent(entries, index)` index is undefined. Please tell me I'm just missing something obvious here.

**EDIT:** This code is causing so many problems tonight :)

```
var clear_show_content;
function showContent(json){
    var entries = json;
    $('#content').html('');
    if(checkIfNoneEntered(entries))
        $('#content').append('<div class="entry">No Alumni Entered Yet!</div>');
    else if(checkIfNoMatches(entries))
        $('#content').append('<div class="entry">No Matches Found!</div>');
    else if(checkIfError(entries))
        $('#content').append('<div class="entry">There was an error!</div>');
    else {
        clearTimeout(clear_show_content);
        $('#content').append('<table border="2" id="content_table" width="50%">');
        var filler = '<img width="1" height="1" />';

        clear_show_content = setTimeout((function(){showContent(entries, 0);}),
                                                                             500);
    }
}

function showContent(entries, index){
    if(index < 0)
        return;

    stop = index + 10 > entries.alumnus.length ? entries.alumnus.length : 10;
    start = new Date();
    for(allIndex = index; allIndex < stop; allIndex++){
}//This is where it becomes proprietary, but I highly doubt the issue is after here
```

**EDIT 2:** Here's a jsFiddle of the issue. It's not working on my browser (Chrome 16) and I don't currently have access to any other browser. I don't think that's the issue though, as I've written code like this hundreds of times. http://jsfiddle.net/eygraber/NduqY/1/

Comment: Code looks fine, you sure _this_ is what's breaking?

Comment: I've been going over it for an hour. There's literally nothing else.

Comment: If the declaration of `showContent` is `showContent(entries, index)` I don't see how `index` could possibly be undefined when you pass through a numeric literal. Can you perhaps show the whole function, or some of the context for where you're running the `setTimeout()` from?

Comment: can you post more code anyway?  :)

Comment: If there's *literally* nothing else, then that's your problem: `showContent()` is undefined. ;)

Comment: It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/gWNdc/

Comment: Obviously something else is the problem - can you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) it for us and reproduce?

Comment: Still don't see anything wrong.  What's happening?  And JS code isn't proprietary :)

Comment: Ok I'm gonna update my post with the jsFiddle (that thing is amazing :) ). I checked for another index variable but as far as I know there isn't one.

Comment: @cwolves lol I know it's not proprietary but there is some of my client's personal information there and I'm too lazy to take it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're defining your `showContent` function twice...

Comment: There's no overloading in js?

Comment: you are overriding it, that's the problem -- your first one gets wiped out and can never be called

Comment: no, you can't overload a function based on argument counts :)  I have code that actually does that if you _really_ want it (by counting arguments and forking to the appropriate function), but it's overkill for almost everything

Comment: Holy **** I wonder how many workarounds I've had too use over the past year not realizing that...

Answer (score 4):

Both your functions are called 'showContent' which means when you try to call the first one, you're really calling the second one because the first is overwritten.

When you check if index is undefined, check what's in entries. I bet it's the json you meant to pass to the first function.